# Java Enum in Perl Inline Java

Tags: java, perl, enums

I use [Inline::Java](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline-Java/lib/Inline/Java.pod) to call a Java library from my Perl code. However, there is one function call I cannot get to work because it requires an enum type as argument.

These are my Java method signatures:

```
public class Initializer {
  [...]     
  public int initializeExtractor() {...}
  public int initializeExtractor(Language... languages) {...}
```

I am trying to call the latter version in Perl:

```
use Inline (
    Java => 'STUDY',

    [...]
    AUTOSTUDY => 1,
    STUDY     => [
               [...],
               'package.Language'
    ],

    JNI     => 0,
);

[...]

my $instance = package::Initializer->new( $self->directory() );
$instance->initializeExtractor($package::Language::ENGLISH);
```

This is the error message:

```
In method initializeExtractor of class package::Initializer: Can't find any signature that matches the arguments passed (package::Language=HASH(0x2328708)).
Available signatures are:
    initializeExtractor([Lpackage.Language;)
        error was: package.Language is not a kind of [Lpackage.Language; at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.4/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Inline/Java/Object.pm line 107.

    initializeExtractor()
        error was: Wrong number of arguments at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.4/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Inline/Java/Object.pm line 107. at /.../PP.pm line 57.
```

Calling the first method (`initializeExtractor()`, without arguments) works such fine which is why I am pretty sure my 'studies' are fine.
However, according to [this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/perl/inline/078nfpcgtd/java-enum-support), I think I do access the Java enum in the right way.

The fact that the Java method has a [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) arguments seems not related to me, is it?

The error message seems a bit misleading because it looks like the first reported available signature matches exactly the argument that I pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The varargs argument is related to you.  The declaration `public int initializeExtractor(Language... languages) {...}` defines a method that expects an Array of `Language` objects, but provides syntactic sugar so that a Java call with a single `Language` argument is coerced into an Array with one element, but it looks like the `Inline::Java` package in Perl has not been sweetened this way:

```
package.Language is not a kind of [Lpackage.Language;
```

i.e., a single `package.Language` argument is not the same thing as a list of `package.Language` objects. You can explicitly provide the list from Perl but enclosing the argument in `[`brackets`]`.

```
$instance->initializeExtractor( [ $package::Language::ENGLISH ] );
```